# Norm of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x$ and $y$ be two vectors. What can you say when $||x||+||y||=||x+y||$?

Comment: What is your space and what norm  are you using? If you are using the standard  norm on an Euclidean space then $x=ay$ for some $a \geq 0$ or  $y=ax$ for some $a \geq 0$.

Answer (score 9):

In $\mathbb R^n$ you may consider geometric view of the relation
$$||x||+||y||=||x+y||$$
it says you have a triangle with sides $x$, $y$ and $x+y$. Such triangle trivially is a segment and therefore $x$, $y$ lie on $x+y$. This shows that $x$ and $y$ are a **positive** multiplier of each other, that is $x=ky$ or $y=kx$, where $k\geqslant0$.

Comment: I don't care the vote, but I like to know where of my answer is wrong.

Comment: Of course. Simply $x=\vec{i}$ and $y=-\vec{i}$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 5):

This is the equality case for [triangular inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) which holds if and only if $x$ and $y$ are multiple vectors with the same direction, that is $y=kx$ with $k>0$ (excluding trivial cases $x=0\,\lor \,y=0$).